# pyautogui not moving window to correct location

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am using pyautogui to move a window to the top left corner of the screen. For some applications such as Excel and Skype, this works correctly. For other applications such as Chrome and Notepad, the window is instead moved to 10 pixels to the right of the upper left hand corner. Why is this happening?

Note that I am using python 3.6 and Windows 10.

See code example below.

```
import pyautogui

window = pyautogui.getWindow('MyChromeWindow')
window.move(0,0)
#window instead moves to (10, 0).
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate the problem , but you can overcome this issue wiht move to picture as i suppose (0,0) is standardbackroud rgb.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code. It worked for me.

```html
import pyautogui

#pyautogui.getAllTitles()   #to get all active titles of windows

pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('MyChromeWindow')[0].moveTo(0,0)
```